# Filtrar fecha mínima de un modelo en DJango

Tags: python, django

necesito mostrar el semestre en el que inicio a estudiar un estudiante, este semestre esta relacionado en la caracterización con la menor fecha de creación **created**.

tengo los siguiente modelos

**Modelo estudiante:**

```
class Estudiante(models.Model):
    TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS = (
        (1,'Tarjeta de indentidad'),
        (2,'Cédula'),
        (3,'Pasaporte'),
        (4,'Cédula extrangera'),
    )
    ESTADOS = (
        (1,'Activo'),
        (2,'Inactivo'),
        (3,'Egresado'),
        (4,'Graduado'),
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombres", max_length=200)
    apellido = models.CharField(verbose_name="Apellidos", max_length=200)
    tipo_documento = models.IntegerField(choices = TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS, default=2)   
    documento = models.CharField(verbose_name="Número de documento", max_length=200)
    celular = models.CharField(verbose_name="Celular", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefono", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, verbose_name="Género", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha de nacimiento")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Correo electronico", null=True, blank=True)
    direccion =  models.CharField(verbose_name="Dirección", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado =models.IntegerField(choices = ESTADOS, default=1)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def semestre_inicio(self):
        inicio = self.caracterizacion_set.filter()
        return inicio
```

**Modelo Caracterizacion:**

```
class Caracterizacion(models.Model):
    SI_NO = (
        (1,'Sí'),
        (2,'No'),
    )
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, verbose_name="Estudiante", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descripción", null=True, blank=True)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, verbose_name="Semestre", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_caracterizacion, verbose_name="Tipo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nivelado = models.IntegerField(choices = SI_NO, default=1)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Usuario", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{} - {}'.format(self.estudiante, self.semestre))
```

**Vista:**

```
{% block content %}

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="white-box">
        <table id="example" class="table display table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>Programa</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Semestre de inicio</th>
                    <th>Caracterizaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>Programa</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Semestre de inicio</th>
                    <th>Caracterizaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                {% for estudiante in estudiante_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{estudiante.nombre}} {{estudiante.apellido}}</td>
                    <td>{{estudiante.documento}}</td>
                    <td><b>{{estudiante.programa}}</b></td>
                    <td>{{estudiante.estado}}</td>
                    <td>{{estudiante.semestre_inicio}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'caracterizacion:list' estudiante.id %}" class="btn btn-block btn-success"> {{estudiante.caracterizacion_set.count}}</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Actualmente en la página me sale Así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que solo se mostrara el 2013-1 o 2013-2 depende de cual de los dos tenga la fecha **created** mas antigua.

Gracias

**Edit**

Realice un for en la vista y ahora me sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta fue la parte de código que modifique

```
<tbody>
    {% for estudiante in estudiante_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{estudiante.nombre}} {{estudiante.apellido}}</td>
        <td>{{estudiante.documento}}</td>
        <td><b>{{estudiante.programa}}</b></td>
        <td>{{estudiante.estado}}</td>
        <td>
            {% for car in estudiante.semestre_inicio %}
                {{ car.semestre }} 
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'caracterizacion:list' estudiante.id %}" class="btn btn-block btn-success"> {{estudiante.caracterizacion_set.count}}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu problema o que es lo que quieres que haga ...

Comment: Te explico, necesito que se vea el semestre en el cual empezo a estudiar el estudiante pero cuando listo las caracterizaciones me salen todas y necesito que se vea solo la que tiene la fecha created mas antigua la cual seria la que se creo cuando se creo el estudiante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use algo como esto:

```
 [QuerySet].aggregate(lowest=Min('created'), highest=Max('created'))
```

Reemplace "[QuerySet]" con el QuerySet que haga falta

Comment: Disculpa, soy nuevo, exactamente en que parte debería agregar esa linea?

Comment: Entiendes que es un QuerySet?

Comment: Según entiendo es una lista de objetos

Comment: Hola, despues de un buen tiempo de investigaciones y avances del proyecto ya se que es un queryset a la perfección y ahora se que lo que me diste es correcto., gracias

Comment: @CesarMartinezQuiroga Me complace oír eso.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Estudiante(models.Model):
    TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS = (
        (1,'Tarjeta de indentidad'),
        (2,'Cédula'),
        (3,'Pasaporte'),
        (4,'Cédula extrangera'),
    )
    ESTADOS = (
        (1,'Activo'),
        (2,'Inactivo'),
        (3,'Egresado'),
        (4,'Graduado'),
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombres", max_length=200)
    apellido = models.CharField(verbose_name="Apellidos", max_length=200)
    tipo_documento = models.IntegerField(choices = TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS, default=2)   
    documento = models.CharField(verbose_name="Número de documento", max_length=200)
    celular = models.CharField(verbose_name="Celular", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefono", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, verbose_name="Género", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha de nacimiento")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Correo electronico", null=True, blank=True)
    direccion =  models.CharField(verbose_name="Dirección", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado =models.IntegerField(choices = ESTADOS, default=1)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    @property
    def semestre_inicio(self):
        caracteristicas = Caracteristicas.objects.filter(estudiante=self)
        fecha_antigua = caracteristicas.order_by('created').first().created
        inicio = caracteristicas.filter(created=fecha_antigua)
        return inicio
```

te he modificado la función "semestre_inicio" prueba a ver si con esto te vale.